# Plotting regression line on scatter plot using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a quadratic regression model. I would like to add the model's 
fitted regression line to a scatter plot. My preference is to use ggplot2.
I am able to draw the scatter plot but when I use "stat_smooth()"
to specify the formula, I get the following warning and the fitted
line is not drawn on the scatter plot.

Warning messages:
1: 'newdata' had 80 rows but variables found have 24 rows 
2: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 80, 24

My code is below. Can someone please guide me what should I do
differently so that I can get fitted regression line in a scatter
plot using ggplot.

Code:

```
library(gamair)
library(ggplot2)
data(hubble)

names(hubble)[names(hubble) == "y"] <- c("velocity")
names(hubble)[names(hubble) == "x"] <- c("distance")

hubble$distance.sqr <- hubble$distance^2
model2.formula <- hubble$velocity ~ hubble$distance + 
   hubble$distance.sqr - 1
model2.hbl <- lm(model2.formula, data = hubble)
summary(model2.hbl)

model2.sp <- ggplot(hubble, aes(x = distance, y = velocity)) +
  geom_point() + labs(title = "Scatter Plot between Distance & Velocity", 
  x = "Distance", y = "Velocity")
model2.sp + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = hubble$velocity ~ 
  hubble$distance + hubble$distance.sqr - 1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the issue here is how you specify the quadratic formula. For the squared term you could use `I(x^2)` or `poly(x, 2)`. For example:

```
ggplot(hubble, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", 
              formula = y ~ x + poly(x, 2) - 1) + 
  labs(x = "Distance", y = "Velocity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is a MWE based on "mpg" dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = hwy, y = displ)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
```